# Create table in chunks - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, clob

I have a table:

table1

```
f_name     f_content
test1.txt  YL*1**50*1~
           RX*1~
           LR*2~
test2.txt  YL*1**49*1~
           EE*1~
           WW*2~
```

SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE table1_with_line
    AS
        SELECT
            f_name,
            level   AS line_num,
            regexp_replace(regexp_substr(t1.f_content, '[^~]+', 1, level), '(^[[:space:]]+)') line
        FROM
            table1 t1
CONNECT BY level <= regexp_count(f_content, '~')
   AND PRIOR f_name = f_name
   AND PRIOR sys_guid() IS NOT NULL;
```

My table table1 has 30,000 records with f_content being in CLOB. Each record in CLOB has around 100 lines separated by ~.

It has been more than 20 hours and the query is still running.

Is there a way I can break it down into multiple chunks in SQL so the table gets created and records are processed in chunks?

Comment: Sample data would help here. The solution may not involve chunks.

Comment: First of all show the explain plan for the SELECT.

Comment: @dang It appears that the query will duplicate each row based on the number of ocurrences of `'~'` within `f_name`. When I tried it for half a dozen rows it returned instantaneously using a single full table scan, so there must be something else going on. For example, if this is a simplified version and the real query contains joins then things can get out of hand very quickly.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson -  have shared sample data and this is the full query.